# Ошибка при нахождении опорных векторов

Tags: python, машинное-обучение

Пытаюсь найти опорные вектора. Но почему то у меня появляется ошибка:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:\machine lerning\week_3\main.py", line 13, in <module>
clf.support_
AttributeError: 'SVC' object has no attribute 'support_'
```

Я вижу, что он выдает о том, что нет такого атрибута, но в документации по данной библиотеке он описан.
https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/svm.html
Вот мой код:

```
import pandas
from sklearn import svm
from sklearn.svm import SVC

data = pandas.read_csv('svm-data.csv', header=None)

x = data.iloc[0]
y = data.iloc[:,1]

clf = SVC(C=100000, kernel='linear', random_state=241)
clf.fit = (y, x)

print(clf.support_)
```

А это данные, по которым происходит обучение:

```
   0.0   0.7  0.29
0  1.0  0.23  0.55
1  0.0  0.72  0.42
2  0.0  0.98  0.68
3  0.0  0.48  0.39
4  1.0  0.34  0.73
5  0.0  0.44  0.06
6  1.0  0.40  0.74
7  0.0  0.18  0.18
8  1.0  0.53  0.53
```

Comment: [Что делать с ответами на вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Как говорилось в старом "политическом" анекдоте про сантехника: "Да тут всю систему менять надо!"

```
from sklearn.svm import SVC
```

`SVC` - это классификатор, а у вас данные непрерывные, а не дискретные, так что нужно воспользоваться регрессором:

```
from sklearn.svm import SVR
```

Далее. Что это такое?

```
x = data.iloc[0]
y = data.iloc[:,1]
```

Вам уже объясняли в другом вопросе, как должны выглядеть срезы для `x` и `y`. И для полной аутентичности добавлю, что `X` должен быть с большой буквы, потому что `X` - это матрица значений, а `y` - это вектор. Матрицы принято называть большими буквами:

```
X = data.iloc[:,:2] # столбцы 0 и 1
y = data.iloc[:,2] # столбец 2
```

Смотрим далее:

```
clf = SVC(C=100000, kernel='linear', random_state=241)
```

Как я уже сказал - будем использовать регрессор. И параметра `random_state` там нет:

```
clf = SVR(C=100000, kernel='linear')
```

Далее. Что это?!

```
clf.fit = (y, x)
```

Вы присваиваете полю `fit` модели `clf` кортеж `(y, x)`. Это явно не то, что вам требовалось. Кормить модель данными нужно так:

```
clf.fit(X, y)
```

И вот уже после этого можете печатать `support_`, теперь он в модели есть:

```
print(clf.support_)
```

**Дополнение "по вновь открывшимся обстоятельствам".**

Целевая колонка у автора вопроса самая первая, и как можно видеть, она на самом деле целочисленная, хоть и представлена в виде с плавающей точкой. В таком случае можно использовать `SVC` (и `random_state`), но нужно опять же правильно подготовить данные. Например, так:

```
X = data.iloc[:,1:] # колонки 1, 2
y = data.iloc[:,0].astype(int) # колонка 0, приведённая к int
```

Остальной код тогда можно использовать ваш, ну, за исключением, конечно, тренировки модели:

```
clf.fit(X, y)
```

Comment: По условию задания я должен использовать класс sklearn.svm.SVC. и обязательно с параметром random_state = 241. А целевая переменная указана в первом столбце, признаки — во втором и третьем. Что мне делать в таком случае?

Comment: @даниласоловьев Я недостаточно внимательно посмотрел, должен был догадаться про первую колонку. Дополнил ответ, в этом случае переделывать ваш код нужно меньше, чем я думал.

Comment: Спасибо большое, что помогли разобраться)